# Index only a few fields in a ElasticSearch mapping

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, indexing, searchable

I'm working with ElasticSearch 6.5.
I have indexed a csv file using the following code:

```
def create_index(es_object, index_name):
    created = False
    # index settings
    settings = {
        "settings": {
            "number_of_shards": 1,
            "number_of_replicas": 0,
            "analysis": {
                "filter": {
                    "dbl_metaphone": { 
                        "type":    "phonetic",
                        "encoder": "beider_morse"
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "dbl_metaphone": {
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "filter":    "beider_morse"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
            "test": {
                #"dynamic": "strict",
                "properties": {
                    "family name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "index": "analyzed",
                        "fields": {
                            "phonetic": { 
                                "type":     "string",
                                "analyzer": "dbl_metaphone"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "Firstname": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "index": "analyzed",
                        "fields": {
                            "phonetic": { 
                                "type":     "string",
                                "analyzer": "dbl_metaphone"
                            }
                        }
                    },

                "Date of birth": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "index": "false"
                },  
                "Place of birth": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "index": "false",
                },

            }
        }
    }
}

    try:
        if not es_object.indices.exists(index_name):
            # Ignore 400 means to ignore "Index Already Exist" error.
            es_object.indices.create(index=index_name, ignore=400, body=settings)
            print('Created Index')
        created = True
    except Exception as ex:
        print(str(ex))
    finally:
        return created
```

The problem is that when I tried to search the data with kibana, all the field are searchable and aggregatable. And i wanted to exclude "Date of birth" and "Place of birth" from searchable and aggregatable.

Can anyone explain whats the problem with my mapping and how to update the index to achieve it?

Thank you

Comment: You really don’t want them to be searchable? What the use of it then?

Comment: I have some columns that are the concatenation of other so i don't want to multiply searches. moreover i'm using kibana ihm but also generate a reporting based on queries in elastic with the python api. To avoid too much results, because i'm using phonetic and fuzziness i have to constrain the search on only some fields. At the end the reporting will contain all the fields ! The option index:false exist but is not working for me and I don't know why

Comment: Could you share your sample document that you’re indexing?

Comment: `first_name;family_name;date_of_birth;place_of_birth;summary
    sam;jones;1980-09-09;New York;sam jones 1980-09-09 New 
    York 
    paris;hilton;1982-01-01;Paris;paris hilton 1980-01-01 Paris
    james;Hook;1780-05-11;London;james Hook 1780-05-11 London`

Comment: So I'd like to index only two first columns to make them searchable and not the rest ! But, I'd like that all columns i.e. fields may appear in kibana

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the index as "not_analyzed"

`"Date of birth": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
                },`

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this with a minimal example (added through Console in Kibana, but you'll be able to change that to plain curl commands quite easily):

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "dynamic": "strict",
      "properties": {
        "family name": {
          "type": "text",
          "index": "true"
        },
        "Firstname": {
          "type": "text",
          "index": "true"
        },
        "Date of birth": {
          "type": "text",
          "index": "false"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT /test/_doc/1
{
  "family name": "foo",
  "Firstname": "bar",
  "Date of birth": "baz"
}
```

This works for me. I can find `foo` and `bar`, but not `baz`:

[image]

Also after refreshing the index pattern the date of birth field is neither searchable nor aggregateable:

[image]

Some quick observations:

1. [`index` is `true` or `false`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html). Its on a different field, so probably not related to your issue.
2. Unless you want to suffer in the future I would avoid spaces in field names. I can just see to many things going wrong.

Comment: Thanks. May I know which version of Kibana and ES that you are using please :) What would you do about whitespaces. For example if your firstname is John David what would you do ?

Comment: That's the latest, 6.5.4. Whitespaces in the field name (you have `"Date of birth"` for example); in the value it's totally fine.

Comment: Could you have a look in management for your Kibana to check if the Date of birth field is searchable and aggregatable please ?

Comment: Added to my answer